# How does AWS CodeBuild get code from CodeCommit into Docker container

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, docker

I don't have much experience with Docker (meaning I only know a few things about writing a `Dockerfile` and about the concepts involved in Docker).
I want to make up a Docker image for CodeBuild to build my application, however I am not sure how CodeCommit will get the code from CodeCommit into my docker image.

I followed [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments/) about extending CodeBuild with custom Docker images but I still can't understand the process of getting code from git into the container.

Could you help me out with some advice, please?

Answer (score 1):

I guess You are using CodePipeline and CodeBuild can get input artifact (zip file). Next step is to copy the code inside container image during build process using:

> COPY {from} {to}

in Dockerfile.

Comment: So is this correctly understood: CodeBuild clones the repository, in which the dockerfile resides at top level and runs docker build. Inside the dockerfile we retrieve the source code by calling 'COPY . /app' where,  in this case, we access current directory with dot [.], and copy it to '/app'? I ask because many of the sites I hit when searching seems to have 'git clone' logic inside dockerfile which surprises me.

Comment: @Hervian yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Codebuild fetch code from codecommit and it will be available for us on $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR folder. Now if you want to copy code to Docker container while running docker build then make sure you will be correct directory ($CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR) and have use COPY command with '.' like below :

COPY ./test /test

If you don't give dot (.) then it definitely show error something like below 
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder095648372/test: no such file or directory

Hopefully helpful for new AWS users.